# Laravel 5.7 Can't write image data to path Image intervention

Tags: laravel-5.7, intervention

I want to save all my uploaded files into public.

Everytime the superadmin create a new company it will create a folder that can be found in the public

```
$path = public_path().'/attachments/'.$company_id;
if (!File::exists($path)) {
                File::makeDirectory($path, 777, true, true);
}
```

When I tried to upload a company logo it gives me an error `"Can't write image data to path (C:\wamp64\www\accubooksv2\public/attachments/10/C-CP//1550648014.jpg)"`

**Controller**

```
$data['company_id'] = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $data['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/attachments/'.$data['company_id'].'/C-CP/';
        // $path = public_path().'/attachments/'.$data['company_id'].'/C-CP/';
        // File::makeDirectory(public_path()."uploads/properties");
        // File::makeDirectory($path,0777,true);
        $img = Image::make($image);
         $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$data['imagename']);
```

Here's an example of created new folder after I created a new company.
[image]

Question: What is the cause of this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: Does Laravel has the required permissions for this directory?

Comment: Im always checking the new created folder whenever I create a new company, modify,read,write,read & execute is allowed(checked)

Comment: I updated my post, I put some example after I created new company.

Answer (score 0):

The clue to the error maybe in the file path:

```
C:\wamp64\www\accubooksv2\public/attachments/10/C-CP//1550648014.jpg)
```

The mixed directory separator could be causing an error. What happens if you change the directory separator from `/` to `\`.

If you want to make your code cross-platform, use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `\` or `/`. E.g.:

```
$path = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'attachments'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $company_id;
```

Or

```
$path = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('attachments', $company_id);
$path = public_path($path);
```